# How to change only child elements with jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to change only childs elements of #div's, is this possible with the following html code and jQuery? The following code change all the inputs with "start" and "end" classes:

```js
$('input.h24').on('change', function() {
  var start = $('.start');
  var end = $('.end');
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    start.val('00:00');
    end.val('24:00');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mon">
  <span>Tue</span>
  <input type="text" class="start" name="mon_start" placeholder="Start" value="">
  <input type="text" class="end" name="mon_end" placeholder="End" value="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="h24" value="1">24hrs</label>
</div>
<div id="tue">
  <span>Tue</span>
  <input type="text" class="start" name="tue_start" placeholder="Start" value="">
  <input type="text" class="end" name="tue_end" placeholder="End" value="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="h24" value="1">24hrs</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work, you can look for the `div` parent of the checkbox using `$.closest`, and then find the appropriate `.start` and `.end` children of that div to modify:

```js
$('input.h24').on('change', function() {
  var start = $(this).closest('div').find('.start');
  var end = $(this).closest('div').find('.end');
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    start.val('00:00');
    end.val('24:00');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mon">
  <span>Mon</span>
  <input type="text" class="start" name="mon_start" placeholder="Start" value="">
  <input type="text" class="end" name="mon_end" placeholder="End" value="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="h24" value="1">24hrs</label>
</div>

<div id="tue">
  <span>Tue</span>
  <input type="text" class="start" name="tue_start" placeholder="Start" value="">
  <input type="text" class="end" name="tue_end" placeholder="End" value="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="h24" value="1">24hrs</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your start and end selectors to be relative to the element being clicked on with `$(this).closest('div').find()`:

```js
$('input.h24').on('change', function() {
  var start = $(this).closest('div').find('.start');
  var end = $(this).closest('div').find('.end');
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    start.val('00:00');
    end.val('24:00');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mon">
  <span>Tue</span>
  <input type="text" class="start" name="mon_start" placeholder="Start" value="">
  <input type="text" class="end" name="mon_end" placeholder="End" value="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="h24" value="1">24hrs</label>
</div>
<div id="tue">
  <span>Tue</span>
  <input type="text" class="start" name="tue_start" placeholder="Start" value="">
  <input type="text" class="end" name="tue_end" placeholder="End" value="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="h24" value="1">24hrs</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple ways to do this, but one way would be to traverse upwards using a combination of [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)(since your `input` is the child of the `label`) and [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)(to target only the siblings of the label)

```js
$('input.h24').on('change', function() {
  var start = $(this).parent().siblings('.start');
  var end = $(this).parent().siblings('.end');
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    start.val('00:00');
    end.val('24:00');
  } else {
    start.val('');
    end.val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mon">
  <span>Tue</span>
  <input type="text" class="start" name="mon_start" placeholder="Start" value="">
  <input type="text" class="end" name="mon_end" placeholder="End" value="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="h24" value="1">24hrs</label>
</div>

<div id="tue">
  <span>Tue</span>
  <input type="text" class="start" name="tue_start" placeholder="Start" value="">
  <input type="text" class="end" name="tue_end" placeholder="End" value="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="h24" value="1">24hrs</label>
</div>
```